# What is the name of the vocal technique of this song

Tags: voice

Can anyone please tell me what is this vocal technique in the following song (2min 23second)

Comment: It sounds a bit like [yodeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yodeling).

Comment: (Note: I've voted to close, but mistakenly chose the wrong reason). A description of the technique needs to be added to this question. Otherwise, should the linked video ever be taken down, the question will lose its value.

Comment: Also the description will help understand which technique is in question.